# Why is ClassName ClassName variable definition in C++ compiling and working properly?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, definition

Say I have a class definition:

```
class CustomClass {
    int member;
};
```

Why is the following variable definition compiling and working correctly:

```
CustomClass CustomClass; // the variable is properly constructed
```

Should't this confuse the compiler and cause it to indicate an error?

Comment: This is what happens when you write compilers ... you have a Class class and that Class class has Method methods.  Then you have meetings where you talk about bugs in the "class class class method method".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Class names and variable names occupy two separate namespaces.  The compiler is able to figure out that the first `CustomClass` is a type and the second `CustomClass` is a variable name.

Comment: The concept of namespaces as you've described here is the correct terminology in C.  In C++, there are rules which specifically allow this without reference to namespaces.  It simply comes down to allowing a type and object, or a type and function where the type is hidden by the other declaration.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand what you're saying here, but from the point of view of the compiler in either C or C++, type names are kept in one list, global variable names in another, local variable names in list for each local scope, etc.  Each of these lists is a "namespace" internal to the compiler (and distinct from the C++ concept of namespaces).

Answer (score 1):

The requested doubt is not necessarily about the case sensitive mode of C++ , it's the variable declaration that has the same name as the class defined above. I'm thinking that your c++ compiler is smart enough to deduce the type of the token that it's parsing ..

Answer (score 0):

I think its compiler magic thats making it work. I agree with you that this ideally should be a compiler error (atleast confuses me).

If you try something like

```
#include <iostream>
class Test { public: int member; };
Test Test;   // comaeu warns 'expression has no effect!'
Test.member = 10; // dosen't compile!

int main(){
  Test Test;   
  Test.member = 10; // compiles fine after global 'Test's are commented!!
  std::cout<<Test.member<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The use of 'Test.member' at global scope will not compile, but the same works inside  'main()' after both the global 'Test's are commented.

C++ has enough complexities to excite programmers, how about compilers too contributing :-) ?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828106/why-is-classname-classname-variable-definition-in-c-compiling-and-working-prope/828125#828125) answer indirectly states the main reason why it is possible to do this in C++.  It comes down to backwards compatibility with C.  In C types had a different namespace and so it was possible to declare a type and object, or a type and function with the same name.

In order to be compatible with C, C++ added some special rules to allow an object or a function to hide the declaration of a type.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not?
Now how to define class CustomClass again?
Easy: use keyword "class", like this:
class  ;
class CustomClass CustomClassAgain;